# Is a two dimensional array such as int[][] part of standard Java runtime?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have an assignment and one of the requirements is: "You may not use any libraries that is related to data structure you have learn, except for the standard Java runtime."

I need to create a two-dimensional as shown below. May i ask if this counts as using libraries related to data structure?

```
int maze[][] = new int[][] 
            {
                {0, 4, 0, 0, 7},
                {4, 0, 1, 2, 0},
                {0, 1, 0, 6, 0},
                {0, 2, 6, 0, 0},
                {7, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            };
```

Comment: You haven't used any libraries in the above code.

Comment: Looks like standard Java runtime to me.

Comment: Yes, it's pure java. You can read more about java arrays [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is java standard. You may also learn more on the official documentation
[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) .